# Unable to build NextJs 14 when using useFormState and useFormStatus

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js14

I'm getting  this errors when building my NextJs App

*./src/pages/login/LoginPageForm.tsx
Attempted import error: 'useFormState' is not exported from 'react-dom' (imported as 'useFormState').*

*./src/pages/login/components/SubmitButton.tsx
Attempted import error: 'useFormStatus' is not exported from 'react-dom' (imported as 'useFormStatus').*

This are my components:

```
// LoginPageForm.tsx

'use client'

import { useFormState } from 'react-dom'
import Alert from './components/Alert'
import Form from './components/Form'
import { LoginAction } from './types'

export default function LoginPageForm({
  loginUser,
}: {
  loginUser: LoginAction
}) {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(loginUser, null)

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className='text-3xl pb-6 text-center'>Log In</h1>
      {!!state?.error && <Alert message={state?.error} />}
      <Form formAction={formAction} />
    </>
  )
}
```

```
'use client'

import { Button } from '@nextui-org/react'
import { useFormStatus } from 'react-dom'

export default function SubmitButton({
  formAction,
  isDisabled,
}: {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  formAction: (payload: FormData) => void
  isDisabled: boolean
}) {
  const status = useFormStatus()

  return (
    <Button
      type='submit'
      color='primary'
      className='mt-4 disabled:opacity-40'
      disabled={isDisabled}
      formAction={formAction}
      isLoading={status.pending}
    >
      Log In
    </Button>
  )
}
```

And my package.lock json looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "store",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nextui-org/react": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^11.0.3",
    "next": "^14.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "^3.2.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

I've tried using react and nextjs canary version but still unable to build my App